# Street, strait, Straße: Die Meerenge von Gibraltar?

Tags: etymology

Both German *Straße* as well as English *street* go back to Late Latin *strata* (from Latin *sternere*, to cover, strew, I think). The superficially similar English *strait*, meaning strict or narrow, however, ultimately  originates from Latin *strictus* (from *stringere*) by some derivation through Old French that is not entirely clear but also not terribly important to me. Romance cognates of *strait* abound, in any case.

Now, sensibly, the English word for a narrow, strict (one might say, strait) waterway connecting two larger bodies of water is *strait*, as in *Strait of Gibraltar*. Just as sensibly, a German word for the same thing is *Meerenge*, literally a *sea strait*.

Much less sensibly, the Strait of Gibraltar (Bonifacio, Malakka, you name it) in German is not called *Meerenge von Gibraltar* or even *Gibraltarenge*, but instead *Straße von Gibraltar*.

I find this odd, in particular considering the lack of a German word *Meer(es)straße*. This leads me to suspect that the appearence of *Straße* in the above uses is the product of an obvious mistranslation of *strait*. I'm using the English word *strait* here, but of course, there is a host of cognates in Romance languages that are perhaps much more likely to be the true culprits when it comes to the question of which word exactly was wrongly translated to German. This is just a detail.

On the other hand, I can see how one might be tempted to call a strait a Straße (after all, it is a path typically used by some kind of traffic), so I'm not sure just how odd to find this, and I'm wondering if it is actually a wrong translation of *strait* or a genuinely new term for *Meerenge*.

Therefore my question:
Is the *Straße* in *Straße von Gibraltar* a street, or is it a bastardized strait?

Edit: All Romance languages exclusively use the respective cognate of *strait* when it comes to describing straits. Germanic languages, apart from English, on the other hand, use their cognate of street for straits, which always sounds close to *strait*. Slavic and Turk languages that do not have a word for street that is sounds just like *strait* do not use the analogy to a street for describing a strait, but different analogies stressing the aspect of narrowness. This supports the hypothesis of a wrong translation.

Comment: "Die Straße von Gibraltar" is very normal. I often read/heard it. The variant with "Meerenge" is used not often in my experience.

Comment: "... in German is not called *Meerenge von Gibraltar* ..." - sorry, but that is not true. It is rarely used, but it is. For Gibraltar as well as for other "Meerengen".

Comment: @IQV Your (I suppose) downvote is nonsensical. The question is about the origin of the prevalent (as you admit yourself) form using _Straße_; of course you can call a Meerenge that is located near Gibraltar the Meerenge von Gibraltar, but that's entirely besides the point.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. And I admit nothing myself.

Comment: @IQV You say _Meerenge von Gibraltar_ is rarely used. Assuming there is no third form that is far more prevalent, this implies that _Straße von Gibraltar_ is the usual form. Maybe one should not call this an admission, but it is a consequence of your statement. Anyway, this is hair-splitting. Which assumption is wrong (serious question; I don't understand what you're referring to)?

Comment: Your assumption I downvoted your question.

Comment: Oh! Well, sorry about that then.

Comment: Think of *Milchstraße* - No connection to an English "strait", not plastered with stones, yet "Straße"

Comment: @tofro Although the question already has a correct answer confirming my suspicion, for the fun of it, I would argue that the _Milchstraße_ is strewn quite literally with stones...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some of your comments, I guess I understand know, what you are after.

[Grimm](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=19,904,44) has a separate entry for *Straße* in the meaning of strait.

It says

> *meerenge. herkunft. lehnwort aus engl.* strait, *pl.* straits *'meerenge', zu* strait *'eng'; dieses aus altfrz.* estreit *(frz.* étroit), *das lat.* strictus *entspricht; vgl. Kretschmer wortgeogr. 494; Torp nynorsk et. ordb. 732. die anwendung des wortes gleicht dem engl. völlig:* the straits of Gibraltar *(seit dem 15. jh.) als* die strasze von Gibraltar; Behring strait *als* Behringstrasze. *engl.* strait, straits *wurde in fälschlicher lehnübersetzung als* strasze, *nd.* strat *übernommen, wahrscheinlich unter verwechslung von engl.* strait *mit engl.* street *'strasze'. heutiges sprachgefühl verbindet* strasze *'meerenge' mit bedeutungen von* <sup>1</sup>strasze *als 'weg auf dem wasser' (s. o. sp. 902, B 4 d) und 'schmaler durchlasz'*

Comment: < sup >1< /sup > (without the spaces).

Comment: @DavidVogt Thank you!

Comment: Oh! Incredible. Grimm surprises me again and again. Thank you.

Comment: @CorneliusBrand Indeed :) You might want to read the full entry. I found it quite interesting.

Answer (score 9):

I guess the Wiki- entries about [Wasserstraße](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstra%C3%9Fe) and [Seeweg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seeweg) might help you. If I may quote (bold font by me):

> Unter einer **Wasserstraße** versteht man schiffbare Flüsse und Kanäle. Meerengen mit dem Attribut **"Straße"** sind **Seestraßen**.

So, naming certain *Meerengen* as *Straße von ...* is rather common in German. Thus, the name *Straße von Gibraltar* is no mistranslation. Further examples are *Straße von Malakka/ Messina/ Kertsch/ Dover/ Hormus/ Tiran/ Sizilien ...* .

Terms like *Wasserstraße*, *Seestraße* or  *Seeweg* are formed in analogy to streets at land, since good sailors don't and didn't travel randomly across the oceans, but used defined routes to optimise for currents, wind and ice conditions, or food and water supply, for example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Judging from a quick corpus search, _Straße von ..._ is a little older than _Seestraße_ or _Wasserstraße_, and the latter two seem to appear mostly in juridical diction. In particular, Straße von Gibraltar appears earlier as Seestraße.

Comment: @CorneliusBrand: you find this need to name a path safe to travel also in aviation: there you have `Luftkorridor` where `Korridor` is known as connection between rooms in a house - which fits figurativly to connections between airports as rooms. Or in landscape you have a `Korridor` for animals to switch habitats. These paths are just not called `Straße`.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that much of the confusion comes from the development in meaning *Straße* has made in the meantime, becoming more specialized to mainly represent asphalted ways, appropriate for cars or even reserved for them.

I see no specific reason to assume a mistranslation, since [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS50847) already provides among dozens of other examples:

> c) verbindungen im sinne von 'durchlasz gewähren, schaffen, sperren', ausgehend von dem sperren der straszen (o. A 1 b), im mhd. noch eng an die eigentliche vorstellung angelehnt:

```
ich füer sô kreftigez her ...  
unt jene die si besâzen
müesen rûmen mir die strâzen
Wolfram von Eschenbach Parzival 768, 4;
```

*Straße* is entirely appropriate if one wants to emphasize the connection aspect as opposed to the narrowness, which is better represented by *Meerenge*, which is also used, even if less frequently.

And finally, this is not restricted to Gibraltar, but also applies to *Maghellanstraße*, *Straße von Malakka* and many others, with the notable exception of the *Northwest-Passage*, the sea route through the Arctic Ocean. Since the latter was much searched for but only recently found in the age of global warming, so the connection aspect was missing for centuries, this seems to fit.

Comment: The meaning of _Straße_ has always been a kind of surfaced road. The latin origin of _Straße_, via strata, translates to plastered (strewn with stone) way, as far as I can gather. I also do not understand how the existence of other  metaphoric uses of _Straße_ helps to answer the question: The very existence of these uses is what makes the question non-trivial. I'm looking for a way to discern the possible metaphorical use of the possible mistranslation. A reason to assume a mistranslation is pointed out both in the edit of my question and in the original question (lack of Meerstraße).